# I can't access to Vuex data: using vue-cli webpack

Tags: vue.js

Right now, I'm trying to show the contents of state object from store.js on my App.vue.

I've tried vuex examples on Medium and other website, but I'm keep failing: non of them worked: some of them even gave me a WebPack config error.

My App.vue

```
<template>
<div id="app">
<img src="./assets/logo.png">
<h1>TEST</h1>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Store from './store/index'

export default {
name: 'App',
Store
}
</script>
```

My store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
state: {
alpha: ['1st data']
},
mutations: {
ADD ({ alpha }) {
  const beta = 'new!'
  state.alpha.push(beta)
   }
  }
})
```

My main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import store from './store/index'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
el: '#app',
store,
components: { App },
template: '<App/>'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be importing the store in `App.vue`. It only needs to be included in `main.js` and passed as an option when constructing the `Vue` instance. Within a component, the store is thereafter accessible via `this.$store`.

Second, your mutation should receive a `context` object as it's first parameter. `context` consists of properties such including `state` and `commit`. Those are the ways in which you access state within a mutation.

```
// notice context is the first parameter
mutations: {
    ADD (context, { param }) {
       const beta = 'new!'
       context.state.alpha.push(beta)
    })
}

// you can also deconstruct context like this
mutations: {
    ADD ({state}, { param }) {
       const beta = 'new!'
       state.alpha.push(beta)
    })
}
```

I also changed the way `alpha` to `param`. You don't receive the state's properties unless you destructure even further.

Comment: Thank you for your advice: I've tried it, but still I get an error: it appears that Vuex is not even recognized by the browser: The Vue devtool tells me that no Vuex store detected :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `main.js` is missing `Vue.use(veux)`

you should have something like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import App from './App'
import store from './store'

Vue.use(Vuex) // <-- Add this

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```